# Can I locate a Google Contact on maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-contacts

How do I locate a contact on Google Maps? I am trying to find an address to their house and the directions. I have tried a search but nothing comes up in the search query.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to do anything, really. Some troubleshooting questions:

- Are you in the U.S.? (I don't believe that this feature is universal.)
- Are you logged in to your Google Account?
- Are you sure you have an address for the contact you're trying to find?

If I'm in Maps and start typing the name of a contact in the search box, their entry appears and I click and jump right to their location on the map. From the pin I can get directions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your contact's address appears automatically on the right spot on Google Maps, provided that the contact is included in the group **My Contacts**. This is the default group to which a newly created contact is assigned. FYI, the contact can also belong to other additional groups if you feel like, but also needs to be in My Contacts.

This feature is not limited to the USA, it's effective worldwide. (cf. @ale's answer)